# How can I activate my AF assist beam on my external flash?

Tags: canon, metz

I have an EOS 650D with a Metz AF-44. The flash has a huge infra lamp but it is not working. I checked the settings on the 650D but the AF support beam is enabled. What other setting should I check? (I checked that it is on Single shot, not on AI servo.)

In the dark I can not use autofocus. With internal flash, I can use it, it is like strobe. But with the external one there is nothing. Neither strobe nor infra.

Comment: Which Metz 44 AF is this? (AF-1 or AF-3?)

Comment: Have you ruled out a defective flash?

Comment: Sorry, it is AF-1. AJ Henderson, i do not understand your question. (sorry but i am not english). What is defective flash?

Comment: Defective = hibas [HUN](http://szotar.sztaki.hu/search?fromlang=eng&tolang=hun&fromlang=eng&tolang=hun&searchWord=defective&langcode=hu&u=0&langprefix=&searchMode=WORD_PREFIX&viewMode=full&ignoreAccents=0)

Answer (score 2):

The [manual for the mecablitz 44 AF-1](https://www.metz.de/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&file=fileadmin/fm-dam/Download/Photo_Electronic/Bedienungsanleitung/mecablitz/mecablitz_40_bis_45/mecablitz_44_AF-1_digital_D_F_NL_GB_I_E.pdf&t=1411738762&hash=d924fb4221c2f2e1d4c571dfd906787e3603d3a8) notes (on page 101) that on some cameras, the AF assist ("measuring beam", they call it) will only work if the camera's center AF point is used, and won't with others. That might be your problem.

The newer [mecablitz 44 AF-3C](https://www.metz.de/index.php?eID=tx_nawsecuredl&u=0&file=fileadmin/fm-dam/Download/Homepage_Englisch/Photo_Electronic/Bedienungsanleitung_GB/mecablitz_GB/mecablitz_40_bis_45/mecablitz_44_AF_3_Canon_GB_I_E.pdf&t=1411738762&hash=5fcf09d049b0e3b7c078052fc37a2d6c51ad4944), mentions a similar limitation (page 48), and also notes that on some cameras, the AF beam is only activated if the camera thinks it is required (although the examples they list seem to only be older cameras).

So, that's my main guess -- make sure you're only using the center focus point.

Also, make sure you have the latest firmware. There's an [update for the 44 AF-1](https://www.metz.de/en/flash-units/firmware-download-flash-units/mecablitz-44-af-1-digital/canon.html), and while there doesn't seem to be one for the AF-3, there probably will be eventually, and often these resolve compatibility quirks.

Comment: It is AF-1. i updatd the softvare and i usually use the middle af point but it stills no working.